# DHCP IP address have access to the internet but static IP address don't behind a router

Tags: router, dhcp, static-ip

I have three PCs

- 192.168.1.100 (DHCP)
- 192.168.1.101 (DHCP)
- 192.168.1.113 (Static)

One router ([SMC SMC8014WN](http://www.smc.com/index.cfm?event=viewProduct&cid=2&scid=19&localeCode=EN_USA&pid=1679))

- 192.168.1.1

The .100 and .101 both have access to the internet. 
The .113 does not.

I check to make sure that .113 is within the DHCP range (.100-.150) of the router. 
I also set a previously working computer .101 to .107 and it could not connect to the internet.

The router is provided by my ISP ([SHAW internet](http://www.shaw.ca/Internet/)) and I do not have the ability to replace it.

**My question is:**

- What would cause a computer with a static IP address not to have access to the WAN while a DHCP'ed computer would.

**Update 1**

What I mean by "Can not access to the WAN" is that I can not ping an external IP address for example .113 can ping .100 and .101 but can not ping 173.194.33.52 (google.com)

I am not using DNS, but just to check I set the DNS to 8.8.8.8 and I am still having the same issue.

Comment: Are you setting the default gateway to the router address?

Comment: @chunkyb2002: Yes I am sure the all three computers have the default gateway set to 192.168.1.1

Comment: Did you set the DNS server on the static PC?  When you say you can't access the internet, what have you tried?  Can you ping an IP address on the internet?  Can you perform hostname lookups (using host, nslookup, or dig)?

Comment: Have you tried pinging any URL? Have you set DNS servers? It should also be set to the router address (unless you have your own dedicated DNS Server) or some external DNS server like Google's 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Comment: Klox, chunkyb2002: No I did not set the DNS, Yes I tried to ping IP address of known computers 173.194.33.52 (google.com) My applications do not require DNS.. I will update my question.

Comment: Try setting the static IP address OUTSIDE of the DHCP range, but in the same subnet?

Comment: Can you tracert to 173.194.33.52? Does it fail at the router or does it get further than that?

Comment: Luke: You are correct! I can not set the static IP address of the PC WITHIN the range of the DHCP. Once I set the static IP address to .160 OUTSIDE the DHCP range, everything worked. Thank you. 

I'm not sure how to accept a comment as the accepted answer

Comment: @Luke: please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it as the solution to this question... per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78895/how-to-handle-an-answer-as-a-comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the static IP address OUTSIDE of the DHCP Range, but still in the same subnet

Comment: Why does this work?

Comment: Why do certain websites work but not others?

Comment: @whoKnows Shaw has fancy Cisco router/modems with many features turned off. I asked for it to be in Bridged mode, and use my own routers/switches behind their modem. It's to prevent collisions of DHCP clients

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set a static IP address to one within the DCHP range, if that particular address has already been reserved.

Comment: Waiting on 'luke' to post a answer this question as he was the first to answer it as a comment, But you are correct as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the IP Address of the router is excluded from the DHCP Range

for example the router IP Address is 192.168.1.1 which also the address of the

DHCP Server  and the Gateway and the DNS,

so the DHCP range should start after the 1  like 2  to 120

Answer (score 0):

dont know if ull see this but i finally figured it out so theres a couple things that were holding me back despite doing all the standard stuff so...

first go onto ur router 192.1.... and advanced and lanip there youll see use this router as dhcp so lower the max value of that to something like 150
seccondly open windows power shell as administrator and type Get-NetConnectionProfile
this will show some details if the network shows public this explains alot of problems with static ip addresses so type Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceIndex *INDEX NUMBER SHOWN* -NetworkCategory Private
third goto network and sharing centre right click your adapter/details/internet protocol 4/details 
then set the ip address to 192.169.0.*any number above 150* to get the rest of the details u need open up cmd and type ipconfig
apply those settings then close it 
now add the services as standard
then the inbound firewall rule to the ip address u set